# What could be the more optimised way to get all unique subarray which equals to a target

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to solve [Combination Sum II on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-ii/). I was able to derive a recursive solution for the problem but it is not optimised as it only beats 10% of the solutions.

---

> 40. Combination Sum II
>
> Given a collection of candidate numbers (candidates) and a target number (target), find all unique combinations in candidates where the candidate numbers sum to target.
>
> Each number in candidates may only be used once in the combination.
>
> **Note:** The solution set must not contain duplicate combinations.
>
> Example 1:
>
> > **Input:** candidates = [10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5], target = 8
> > **Output:**
> > [
> > [1, 1, 6],
> > [1, 2, 5],
> > [1, 7],
> > [2, 6]
> > ]
>
> Example 2:
>
> > **Input:** candidates = [2, 5, 2, 1, 2], target = 5
> > **Output:**
> > [
> > [1, 2, 2],
> > [5]
> > ]
>
> Constraints:
>
> - 1 <= candidates.length <= 100
> - 1 <= candidates[i] <= 50
> - 1 <= target <= 30

---

```
def combinationSum2(self, candidates, target): 
    res = []
    def helper(arr,index,curr_sum,ans):
        if curr_sum == target:
            #ans = sorted(ans)
            if ans not in res:
                res.append(ans)
            return
        if len(arr) == index or curr_sum > target:
            return
            
        helper(arr,index+1,curr_sum + arr[index],ans +[arr[index]])

        while len(arr)-1 > index and arr[index] == arr[index+1]:
            index += 1
        helper(arr,index+1,curr_sum,ans)

        return res

    return helper(sorted(candidates),0,0,ans=[])
```

What could I improve in my code or
how can I optimise it better by following the same recursive approach?

Comment: "it only beats 10% of the solutions" did you try running the tests multiple times? I have had algorithms be both top and bottom 10% -- only difference is I ran the _same_ code at different times. I only ask because I wrote my own solution which _should_ be somewhat performant and I'm getting [almost identical results to you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFq7H.png).

Comment: @Peilonrayz let me try at different time in that case. Can you guide on how you plotted the graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First lets clean up your code.

   ```py
   def combination_sum_2(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> list[list[int]]:
       def inner(terms: list[int], curr_sum: int, index: int) -> None:
           if curr_sum == target:
               if terms not in res:
                   res.append(terms)
               return

           if index == len(candidates) or target < curr_sum:
               return

           inner(terms + [candidates[index]], curr_sum + candidates[index], index + 1)

           while index + 1 < len(candidates) and candidates[index] == candidates[index+1]:
               index += 1

           inner(terms, curr_sum, index + 1)

       res: list[list[int]] = []
       candidates = list(sorted(candidates))
       inner([], 0, 0)
       return res
   ```
2. You are wasting time by filtering duplicates within `inner` rather than once outside `inner`.

   ```py
   while index + 1 < len(candidates) and candidates[index] == candidates[index+1]:
       index += 1
   ```

   ```py
   def combination_sum_2(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> list[list[int]]:
       def inner(index: int, curr_sum: int, terms: list[int]) -> None:
           if curr_sum == target:
               if terms not in res:
                   res.append(terms)
               return

           if index == len(candidates) or target < curr_sum:
               return

           inner(index + 1, curr_sum + candidates[index], terms + [candidates[index]])
           inner(index + 1, curr_sum, terms)

       res: list[list[int]] = []
       candidates = list(sorted(set(candidates)))
       inner(0, 0, [])
       return res
   ```
3. Using recursion for looping is a bad idea in Python.

   ```py
   >>> def loop(n: int) -> int:
   ...     def inner(n: int) -> int:
   ...         if not n:
   ...             return 0
   ...         else:
   ...             return inner(n - 1)
   ...     assert 0 <= n
   ...     return inner(n)
   ... 
   >>> loop(1000)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "<stdin>", line 8, in loop
     File "<stdin>", line 6, in inner
     File "<stdin>", line 6, in inner
     File "<stdin>", line 6, in inner
     [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
   ```

   As such rather than using the FP looping mechanic we should just loop over a range.

   ```py
   if index == len(candidates) or ...:
       return

   ...

   inner(terms, curr_sum, index + 1)
   ```

   ```py
   def combination_sum_2(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> list[list[int]]:
       def inner(terms: list[int], curr_sum: int, index: int) -> None:
           if curr_sum == target:
               if terms not in res:
                   res.append(terms)
               return

           if target < curr_sum:
               return

           for i in range(index, len(candidates)):
               v = candidates[index]
               inner(terms + [v], curr_sum + v, i + 1)

       res: list[list[int]] = []
       candidates = list(sorted(set(candidates)))
       inner(0, 0, [])
       return res
   ```
4. Given the constraints we can pre-calculate the end index.
   When `curr_sum` is 13 and the `target` 30 then the max option is 17.
   Checking if 18+ sum to 30 is a waste of time.

   > - 1 <= candidates[i] <= 50
   > - 1 <= target <= 30

   We can build an array containing the index of the highest value which can be added to.
   Then we use `range(index, high_index[target - curr_sum])`.

   ```py
   import bisect


   def rstretch__index(values: list[int], length: int) -> list[int]:
       return [
           bisect.bisect(values, i) - 1
           for i in range(length)
       ]


   def combination_sum_2(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> list[list[int]]:
       def inner(terms: list[int], curr_sum: int, lo: int, hi: int) -> None:
           if curr_sum == target:
               if terms not in res:
                   res.append(terms)
               return

           for i in range(lo, hi):
               c = candidates[index]
               inner(terms + [c], curr_sum + c, i + 1, high_index[target - curr_sum - c])

       res: list[list[int]] = []
       amounts = [0] * (target + 1)
       for c in candidates:
           if c <= target:
               amounts[c] += 1
       candidates = [i for i, c in enumerate(amounts) if c]
       high_index = rstretch__index(candidates, target + 1)
       if amounts[target]:
           res.append([target])
       inner([], 0, 0, len(candidates))
       return res
   ```
5. I prefer using Pythons generator functions.

   ```py
   from typing import Iterator


   def combination_sum_2(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, ...]]:
       def inner(terms: tuple[int, ...], curr_sum: int, lo: int, hi: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, ...]]:
           if curr_sum == target:
               yield terms
               return

           for i in range(lo, hi):
               c = candidates[index]
               yield from inner(terms + [c], curr_sum + c, i + 1, high_index[target - curr_sum - c])

       amounts = [0] * (target + 1)
       for c in candidates:
           if c <= target:
               amounts[c] += 1
       candidates = [i for i, c in enumerate(amounts) if c]
       high_index = rstretch__index(candidates, target + 1)
       yield from inner([], 0, 0, len(candidates))
   ```
6. We can move the `if curr_sum == target` into the loop by using `if amounts[target - curr_sum]`. We will need to handle if `target` is in `candidates` outside `inner` too.

   ```py
   def combination_sum_2(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, ...]]:
       def inner(terms: tuple[int, ...], curr_sum: int, lo: int, hi: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, ...]]:
           for i in range(lo, hi):
               v = candidates[i]
               curr = curr_sum + v
               c = target - curr
               if amounts[c] and i <= high_index[c]:
                   yield terms + (c,)
               yield from inner(terms + (v,), curr, i + 1, high_index[target - curr])

       amounts = [0] * (target + 1)
       for c in candidates:
           if c <= target:
               amounts[c] += 1
       candidates = [i for i, c in enumerate(amounts) if c]
       high_index = rstretch__index(candidates, target + 1)
       if amounts[target]:
           yield (target,)
       yield from inner((), 0, 0, len(candidates))
   ```

<sub>**Note**: No code in the answer has been validation tested.</sub>

[image]

Code to make graph:

```py
import bisect
import collections
from typing import Iterator


def test_orig(candidates, target): 
    res = []
    def helper(arr,index,curr_sum,ans):
        if curr_sum == target:
            #ans = sorted(ans)
            if ans not in res:
                res.append(ans)
            return
        if len(arr) == index or curr_sum > target:
            return
            
        helper(arr,index+1,curr_sum + arr[index],ans +[arr[index]])

        while len(arr)-1 > index and arr[index] == arr[index+1]:
            index += 1
        helper(arr,index+1,curr_sum,ans)

        return res

    return helper(sorted(candidates),0,0,ans=[])


# A failed generalization of the 3SUM problem
def nsum(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, ...]]:
    candidates_seen_: dict[int, list[tuple[list[int], list[int]]]]
    candidates_seen: dict[int, list[tuple[list[int], list[int]]]] = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(candidates):
        if c < target:
            candidates_seen.setdefault(c, []).append(([i], [c]))
    for _ in range(len(candidates)):
        for i in range(len(candidates)):
            a = candidates[i]
            for j in range(i + 1, len(candidates)):
                b = candidates[j]
                for (indexes, c) in candidates_seen.get(target - a - b, []):
                    if j < indexes[0]:
                        yield a, b, *c
        candidates_seen_ = {}
        for c, seen in candidates_seen.items():
            for (indexes, terms) in seen:
                i = indexes[-1]
                for j, d in enumerate(candidates[i + 1:], start=i + 1):
                    if c + d < target:
                        candidates_seen_.setdefault(c + d, []).append((indexes + [j], terms + [d]))
        candidates_seen = candidates_seen_
        if not candidates_seen:
            break


def test_peil(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> list[tuple[int, ...]]:
    return list(nsum(candidates, target))


def rstretch__index(values: list[int], length: int) -> list[int]:
    return [
        bisect.bisect(values, i) - 1
        for i in range(length)
    ]


def nsum2(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, ...]]:
    def inner(terms: tuple[int, ...], curr_sum: int, lo: int, hi: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, ...]]:
        for i in range(lo, hi):
            v = candidates[i]
            curr = curr_sum + v
            c = target - curr
            if amounts[c] and i <= high_index[c]:
                yield terms + (c,)
            yield from inner(terms + (v,), curr, i + 1, high_index[target - curr])

    amounts = [0] * (target + 1)
    for c in candidates:
        if c <= target:
            amounts[c] += 1
    candidates = [i for i, c in enumerate(amounts) if c]
    high_index = rstretch__index(candidates, target + 1)
    if amounts[target]:
        yield (target,)
    yield from inner((), 0, 0, len(candidates))


def test_peil2(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> list[tuple[int, ...]]:
    return list(nsum2(candidates, target))


def nsum3(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> Iterator[tuple[int, ...]]:
    amounts = [0] * (target + 1)
    for c in candidates:
        if c <= target:
            amounts[c] += 1
    candidates = [i for i, c in enumerate(amounts) if c]
    high_index = rstretch__index(candidates, target + 1)

    stack: list[tuple[int, Iterator[int], int]] = [(0, iter(range(len(candidates))), 0)]
    while stack:
        try:
            i = next(stack[-1][1])
        except StopIteration:
            stack.pop()
            continue
        v = candidates[i]
        curr_sum = stack[-1][2] + v
        c = target - curr_sum
        if amounts[c] and i <= high_index[c]:
            s = iter(stack)
            next(s, None)
            yield tuple(f[0] for f in s) + (c,)
        stack.append((i + 1, iter(range(i + 1, high_index[target - curr_sum])), curr_sum))


def test_peil3(candidates: list[int], target: int) -> list[tuple[int, ...]]:
    return list(nsum3(candidates, target))



import functools
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy
import graphtimer

random.seed(42401)


@functools.cache
def args_conv(size: int) -> tuple[list[int], int]:
    return random.choices(range(101), k=int(size)), 30


def main():
    fig, axs = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
    axs.set_yscale('log')
    axs.set_xscale('log')
    (
        graphtimer.Plotter(graphtimer.MultiTimer([test_orig, test_peil, test_peil2, test_peil3]))
            .repeat(10, 10, numpy.logspace(0, 2, num=50), args_conv=args_conv)
            .min()
    ).plot(axs, x_label='len(nums)')
    fig.show()
    matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('foo.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```